# Webpart to rotate through images?

Tags: web-part, list, picture-library, image

I downloaded this webpart to rotate through images stored in a library however, it seems that the library of images MUST be on the same page as the image rotator for it to work...

Any idea how to extend this so the library of images is on a different site but I can link to them from the image rotator? Or a free web part that would do this?

This is th web part I have been trying to use but has the above issue http://spadrotator.codeplex.com/

Thanks!

Comment: What i understand is that this web-part works only within that site not site collection. you want a web-part that will fetch images from anywhere within site collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to accomplish this, I used this Image Rotator - http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/03/31/quick-update-image-rotator-in-sharepoint-2010/

Simple and works well, it even creates all code for you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use "picture Library Slideshow webpart" and specify time frame like 5 secs to rotate images on a page which are stored in Images Library or any picture Library.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, I can't see libraries located in another site, just the ones under tha same site. Am I doing something wrong with the Picture Library Slideshow Web Part? No list shows up in the dropdown since its in another site...

Answer (score 1):

picture Library Slideshow webpart is good in terms of displying the Images and rotating but it wouldnt help to set the Frame of the Picture because it would be Picture depended.